# Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings in android

Tags: android, location

This is the print of the log which I am getting while trying to execute the code for finding Location using Network Connection:

```
03-12 22:26:17.294: E/ActivityThread(298): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
03-12 22:26:17.305: E/ActivityThread(298): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
03-12 22:26:17.334: E/ActivityThread(298): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
03-12 22:26:17.744: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 2080 objects / 135712 bytes in 124ms
03-12 22:26:17.864: D/LocationManager(298): Constructor: service = android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy@44eabfc0
03-12 22:26:17.964: I/MapActivity(298): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
03-12 22:26:17.974: E/MapActivity(298): Couldnt get connection factory client
03-12 22:26:18.414: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 4356 objects / 255984 bytes in 97ms
03-12 22:26:18.805: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 10577 objects / 968024 bytes in 81ms
03-12 22:26:19.514: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 2347 objects / 313456 bytes in 74ms
03-12 22:26:20.434: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 1222 objects / 237896 bytes in 77ms
03-12 22:26:21.166: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 423 objects / 20192 bytes in 93ms
03-12 22:26:22.035: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 322 objects / 15608 bytes in 79ms
03-12 22:26:22.975: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 573 objects / 56872 bytes in 94ms
03-12 22:26:23.985: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 332 objects / 14656 bytes in 81ms
03-12 22:26:24.985: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 340 objects / 14992 bytes in 76ms
03-12 22:26:26.055: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 338 objects / 14928 bytes in 79ms
03-12 22:26:27.096: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 338 objects / 14936 bytes in 85ms
03-12 22:26:28.145: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 346 objects / 15248 bytes in 81ms
03-12 22:26:29.895: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 945 objects / 73760 bytes in 91ms
03-12 22:26:31.895: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 777 objects / 70376 bytes in 82ms
03-12 22:26:33.075: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 357 objects / 15536 bytes in 82ms
03-12 22:26:34.635: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 350 objects / 15568 bytes in 74ms
03-12 22:26:35.684: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 424 objects / 19480 bytes in 76ms
03-12 22:26:36.764: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 339 objects / 14960 bytes in 88ms
03-12 22:26:37.824: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 339 objects / 14968 bytes in 84ms
03-12 22:26:38.864: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 339 objects / 14952 bytes in 81ms
03-12 22:26:39.966: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 338 objects / 14912 bytes in 81ms
03-12 22:26:41.004: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 340 objects / 14992 bytes in 89ms
03-12 22:26:41.424: D/AndroidRuntime(298): Shutting down VM
03-12 22:26:41.424: W/dalvikvm(298): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-12 22:26:41.424: E/AndroidRuntime(298): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at com.dri.pac.DRIOActivity$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(DRIOActivity.java:126)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:179)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:112)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:128)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-12 22:26:41.444: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 22:26:41.464: I/dalvikvm(298): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-12 22:26:41.494: I/dalvikvm(298): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-12 22:26:43.064: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 593 objects / 62920 bytes in 83ms
03-12 22:26:45.504: D/dalvikvm(298): GC freed 174 objects / 46888 bytes in 79ms
03-12 22:26:46.215: I/Process(298): Sending signal. PID: 298 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not the right APIkey !!

try this :

@echo off
chdir "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"

keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\NEO.android\debug.keystore"

pause

cls